# load csv and set parameters in jupyter notebook on Azure ML

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using a Python 3.4 Jupyter notebook to load a dataset in Azure ML which is stored in the cloud as a dataset in the Azure ML project environment. But using the default template created by Azure ML, I can't load the data due to a mixed datatypes error.

```
from azureml import Workspace
import pandas as pd

ws = Workspace()
ds = ws.datasets['rossmann-train.csv']
df = ds.to_dataframe()
```

> /home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/kernel/**main**.py:6: DtypeWarning: Columns (7) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

In my local environment I just import the dataset as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv',low_memory=False)
```

But I'm not sure how to do this in azure using the `ds` object.

```
df = pd.read_csv(ds)
```

and

```
pd.DataFrame.from_csv(ds)
```

raise the error:

> OSError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got  type

*edit: more info on the `ds` object:

```
In  [1]: type(ds)
Out [1]: azureml.SourceDataset
In  [2]: print (ds)
Out [2]: rossmann-train.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not sure, by your question, what is the `ds` object. But I'm pretty sure it is not a `csv` file, since, if it were, you'd have processed it your self and you wouldn't be having this question.

Now, I am not sure whether `pandas` has a native way of dealing with Azure, but this piece of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-data-science-explore-data-blob) indicates that first you must download the data form Azure, using their package, and save it into your local file system.

But for that, they are assuming that the data you downloaded is already in the `csv` format. If not, use the appropriate reader (or parse it by hand) in order to tabulate the data for a `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: I think the `ds` object is created by the azureml python library which I've imported. I've added more detail on the `ds` object in the question above.

Note the dataset I'm reading is in the cloud, it is stored within my Azure ML studio in the 'datasets' section. The file is definitely a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-MachineLearning-ClientLibrary-Python) on the azureml library, one workaround would be to import the file as text then parse it into csv but this seems unnecessary since the data is already recognised as being in csv structure.

```
text_data = ds.read_as_text()
```